# How to initialize boost::process::child(boost process 0.5)?

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to store the child of boost::process, but do not know how to initialize it

OS : win7 64 bits
compiler : msvc2008 32bits
boost : 1_55_0

example after simplify

```
#include <boost/process/initializers.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>

#include <iostream>

void test_boost_system()
{
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    namespace bpi = boost::process::initializers;

    //bp::child child; //#1

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    bp::child child_2 = bp::execute(bpi::run_exe("ldapInterface.exe"), bpi::set_on_error(ec));
    if(ec.value() != 0){
        std::cout<<ec.message()<<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"success"<<std::endl;
    }    
}
```

How could I initialize the child if I do not want to use the execute to initialize it in place?

pseudo codes :

```
namespace bp = boost::process;
namespace bpi = boost::process::initializers; 

class process_manager
{
public:
    ~process_manager() { bp::terminate(child_); }

    void open_process(std::string const &process)
    {

       child_ = bp::execute(bpi::run_exe(process)); //compile error
    }

private:
    bp::child child_;
};
```

error message : 
error C2512: 'boost::process::windows::child' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: Maybe Following the philosophy of C++, you should have a constructor that initializes `child_`, `public: process_manager(Args...) : child_(Args...){}`. and an empty destructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a wrapper that allows you to lazily initialize.

E.g.

```
class process_manager
{
public:
    ~process_manager() { if (child_) bp::terminate(*child_); }

    void open_process(std::string const &process)
    {
        child_ = bp::execute(bpi::run_exe(process)); //compile error
    }

private:
    boost::optional<bp::child> child_;
};
```